# How to retrace this topology?

Tags: modeling, topology, retopology

I have got my hand on this mesh with a very clean topology recently  and I want to learn how the creator did it, to no avail. The hardest part is where the groin joint with the thigh. The thigh loop has 34 vertices but the one above it has 36, I dont know how did they join them together, bridge loop always messed this up. Can you gives me some advices and if possible, can you check out the model, please?[image: topology]
[image]

Here is the blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9idvodi7r3ftpit/topology.blend/file

Comment: Can you upload the file which shows the situation in the screenshot? It would also be better to use https://blend-exchange.com/ than some external file hoster.

Comment: Could you please highlight the part that has 34 vertices and the part that has 36? Are you talking about the gap in your picture? The mesh you share has no gap...

Comment: @taiyo Sorry I dont know how to use blend-exchange file hoster but I have included a mediafire link above.

Comment: @moonboots I updated the post with the image!

Comment: The question how is a bit vague, we don't know how he modeled his mesh because there are many ways to do it, but I guess he began with a low-poly, as for the number of vertices, it goes from 35 to 36 because there's a pole

Comment: On https://blend-exchange.com/ there is a field which says "Enter the url of the question on blender.stackexchange". Drag'n'drop the model, enter the URL of your question and click _Upload_, done. And again, the model with the unconnected leg would be more useful.